# Intellij not picking up project subfolder main class as executable

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot maven project that is not compiling 'unable to find main class'.  The code was working when I built it and pushed it to bitbucket.  I had to delete the project and start over so I cloned repository and pulled. Now it will not run.  I get an error that the main class is not found.  When I set the subdirectory (actual project) src to source dirctory it still does not compile.  Please let me know what steps I need to take to get the subdirectory of the project to run. The error message I am getting when I build is Error:java: invalid source release: 11

Project folder structure is:
    WeekOne
       CompanyManagement
          src

Here is the main class:

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompanyManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompanyManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the POM file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.novare</groupId>
<artifactId>CompanyManagement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CompanyManagement</name>
<description>Week 1 Test</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

Comment: I pulled the project from bit bucket without opening it then went in and opened the subfolder as a project and it was recognized as a maven project and was built.

Comment: please post  your main class, project structure and pom..

Comment: If I open project and then select the CompanyManagement subfolder the project will run